# Unable to generate POJO(model) class using Gson format

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to parse JSON using Retrofit 2.1.0 library so i used Gson format plugin for creating POJO (model) class but I am not able to create it because of this Gson format exception error  --

```
 com.intellij.util.IncorrectOperationException: Incorrect field '/** 
           * 0 : {"lat":"23.0124","long":"72.5228","question":"caluculate 1+2","hint":"1,2,3","questionAudioUrl":"http://audio/1480919241.mp3"}
           * type : type1
           */ 
           @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("0")private  0Bean value0 ; '
```

And my JSON is also valid I am validating using this site http://jsonformatter.org/

Here is my  **json**

```
    {
  "response": {
    "result": true,
    "errorCode": 0,
    "errorDescription": "Success",
    "tourData": {
      "TourID": "5",
      "sTourName": "titanium city center ahmedabad",
      "sShortDescription": "ffjk fdjf fdjf fd f jkdf fjdf fdf f fhfjd fj jfjfjdhfhfhfdf f fjhf",
      "sLongDescription": "dsd dsd ds dsd dsd d sdsd ds dsd sds dd",
      "sCity": "ahmedabad",
      "sLatitude": "23.0124",
      "sLongitude": "72.5228",
      "sGoalLat": "-2.09",
      "sGoalLong": "12.5228",
      "sVersion": "1",
      "dDate": "2016-11-29 00:41:32",
      "status": "APPROVED",
      "iTourImagesID": "18",
      "iTourID": "5",
      "iImageData": "http://myurl/images/tour-images/1480405309background_menu.jpeg",
      "bIsDefault": "1",
      "dDateTime": "2016-11-29 13:11:49"
    },
    "tourCountData": {
      "total_image": "4",
      "total_coin": "12",
      "total_diamond": "1",
      "total_clues": "3",
      "total_checkpoint": "1"
    },
    "TourAllImageData": [
      {
        "iImageData": "http:///images/tour-images/1480405309background_menu.jpeg",
        "bIsDefault": "1"
      },
      {
        "iImageData": "http://images/tour-images/1480405310background_menu@2x.jpeg",
        "bIsDefault": "1"
      },
      {
        "iImageData": "http:///images/tour-images/1480405312background_menu-568@2x.jpeg",
        "bIsDefault": "1"
      },
      {
        "iImageData": "http://images/tour-images/1480405313background_menu@2x~ipad.jpeg",
        "bIsDefault": "1"
      }
    ],
    "img_result": true,
    "TourAllUserData": [],
    "u_result": false,
    "TourcoinsData": [
      {
        "sLatitude": "19.422655",
        "sLongitude": "-99.161297",
        "iTourPlaceID": "10"
      },
      {
        "sLatitude": "23.0135",
        "sLongitude": "72.5228",
        "iTourPlaceID": "12"
      },
      {
        "sLatitude": "23.0150",
        "sLongitude": "72.5296",
        "iTourPlaceID": "13"
      },
      {
        "sLatitude": "23.0150",
        "sLongitude": "72.5245",
        "iTourPlaceID": "14"
      },
      {
        "sLatitude": "23.0160",
        "sLongitude": "72.5310",
        "iTourPlaceID": "15"
      },
      {
        "sLatitude": "23.0115",
        "sLongitude": "72.5228",
        "iTourPlaceID": "16"
      },
      {
        "sLatitude": "23.0135",
        "sLongitude": "72.5296",
        "iTourPlaceID": "17"
      },
      {
        "sLatitude": "23.0115",
        "sLongitude": "72.5200",
        "iTourPlaceID": "18"
      },
      {
        "sLatitude": "23.0135",
        "sLongitude": "72.5270",
        "iTourPlaceID": "19"
      },
      {
        "sLatitude": "23.0135",
        "sLongitude": "72.5260",
        "iTourPlaceID": "20"
      },
      {
        "sLatitude": "23.0160",
        "sLongitude": "72.5296",
        "iTourPlaceID": "21"
      },
      {
        "sLatitude": "23.0170",
        "sLongitude": "72.5310",
        "iTourPlaceID": "22"
      }
    ],
    "co_result": true,
    "TourDiamondData": [
      {
        "sLatitude": "23.011487",
        "sLongitude": "72.525011",
        "iTourPlaceID": "24",
        "sPlaceImage": "http:/images/places/1481007650-place.png",
        "sPlaceDescription": "dd d dh hffh idufhfhf hf hfhd fhf hdfhufh ffdufh fhdfu dfhd fhd fhdfhdufduf hfhdfhd fhdfhdf dfhdufd ffdufh fhdufd ffhduf ufufh"
      }
    ],
    "di_result": true,
    "TourCheckpointData": [
      {
        "sLatitude": "23.0225",
        "sLongitude": "72.5714",
        "iTourPlaceID": "23"
      }
    ],
    "chk_result": true,
    "TourClueData": [
      {
        "sClues": "clue1"
      },
      {
        "sClues": "clue2"
      },
      {
        "sClues": "clue3"
      }
    ],
    "clu_result": true,
    "TourChallenge1Data": {
      "0": {
        "lat": "23.0124",
        "long": "72.5228",
        "question": "caluculate 1+2",
        "hint": "1,2,3",
        "questionAudioUrl": "http://audio/1480919241.mp3"
      },
      "type": "type1"
    },
    "TourChallenge2Data": {
      "0": {
        "lat": "23.0143",
        "long": "72.5296",
        "question": "type2",
        "hint": "1,,,2",
        "timer": "01:01:00",
        "questionAudioUrl": "http://audio/1480919413.mp3"
      },
      "type": "Type2"
    },
    "TourChallenge3Data": {
      "0": {
        "lat": "23.011641",
        "long": "72.523917",
        "puzzleImageUrl": "http:/images/puzzles/1480919458-puzzle.png",
        "puzzleDescription": "set image",
        "puzzleAudioUrl": "http:/audio/1480919458.mp3"
      },
      "type": "Type3"
    },
    "TourChallenge4Data": {
      "0": {
        "lat": "23.0124",
        "long": "72.5210",
        "keyLat": "23.0135",
        "keyLong": "72.5228"
      },
      "type": "Type4"
    }
  }
}
```

I know there is http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate model class but it create separate classes not nested class so it's hard to manage so many classes.

**QUE 1:** How can i generate model class using json?

**QUE 2:** Is there any way i can get string response using retrofit 2.1.0 i tried `RequestBody` but not work.

Is there any better solution for that??

Comment: You are allowed to nest the objects that are returned from that generator, I believe

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

This is the sample of your json object.Please check it ,try with that ways.

Comment: @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("index.php/App_controller/googleuser_login")
    Call<ResponseBody> google_login(@FieldMap HashMap<String, Object> hashMap);

Comment: this is the way to get the body object

Comment: .enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                            Utility.hideProgressHud(); 
                                String responseString = response.body().string();

Comment: @Lovekesh sorry for my late reply but this is generate multiple classes which is not i won't.

Comment: @ArpitPatel What was the issue with that.

Comment: no it's simple to manage not the hectic thing to get the json ,all the things are done by the http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: also used databinding used this things more simpler.

Answer (score 0):

1) I am not too familiar with the Gson formatter plugin, but it looks like it is generating an invalid type name "0Bean".  It looks like you can edit the names and types of what it generates.  Otherwise, using the site you mentioned or hand coding the POJOs are options.  Also, if you able to rename elements in your JSON, don't name fields with numbers like "0".

2) You can get a string response by using the scalars converter --

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(/* your url */)
    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) /* if you also still need GSON, if not, you can leave this off */
    .build();
```

and in your interface --

```
@GET("/mypath")
Call<String> getMyStuff();
```

You will need to add -- `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'` to your gradle file.

Comment: but in some cases i need GsonConverter

Comment: You can have two converters like in the code above.  The first converter gets priority, but only converts basic types (String, int, float, double, etc).  You specify any other class the gson converter will be used.

Comment: So ScalarsConverterFactory is working with both single variable as well as POJO???

Comment: No, it only handles basic types, and lets the next converter (Gson in this case) handle the POJOs.

Comment: i found simple solution just use one line  String  bodyString = new String(response.body().bytes()); and Thanks for answer and reply.